# Слово "пирог"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Вопрос о "пирожном" натолкнул на мысль: а имеет ли слово "пирог" отношение к греческому слову "пирос" - "огонь"? Или это чисто русское слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фасмер предполагает связь с русским "пир" и отвергает сближение с греческими πύργος (бащня) и непонятным πυργῶτις (см. последнюю фразу в цитате). Что касается πυρός, то это слово переводится гуглом как "пожар" и вряд ли может быть как-то связано с "пир" или "пирог". 
Впрочем, я совсем не знаток греческого.

пирог
пиро́г род. п. -ога́, укр. пирíг, род. п. -ога́, блр. пiро́г, чеш., слвц. piroh, польск. pirog. Образование с суф. -оgъ (ср. Вондрак, Vgl. Gr. 1, 629) – от pirъ (см. пир); ср. Мi. Vgl. Gr. 2, 283; И. IIIмидт, KZ 23, 292. Другие предполагают праслав. *руrоgъ, связанное с др.-русск. пыро "полба" (см. пырей, пыро), откуда получено* pirogъ в результате преобразования по народн. этимологии в связи с пир (Соболевский, РФВ 66, 348; Преобр. II, 60). Невероятно сближение с *рьrаti "бить, колотить" (Бернекер у Янко, WuS 1, 98) или с лит. spìrgti, spìrgau "поджаривать (кусочки сала)", вопреки Фортунатову (ВВ 3, 69), Гуйеру (LF 36, 59). Невозможно произведение от ст.-слав. пира "сума" (см. выше пи́ра), т. е. якобы "пирог на дорогу" (Штрекель, AfslPh 28, 512), потому что это греч. заимствование имело слишком незначительное распространение и его как раз не было у зап. славян, в то время как южн. славяне не знают слова* рirоgъ. Невероятно также, ввиду отсутствия этого слова в южн.-слав., происхождение из чув. pürǝk, крым.-тат., тур., чагат. böräk "пирог с мясом", вопреки Рамстедту (KWb. 67), Рясянену (FUF 29, 198; ZfslPh 20, 448). Лтш. pìrãgs "пирог", эст. piirag "пирог", фин. piiras (основа *рiirаа- с новым -s в фин.), карельск., олон. piiroa "пирожок"; см. М.–Э. (3, 233), Миккола (Berühr. 62), Сетэлэ (YÄН 61 и сл.), Фасмер (RS 6, 185 и сл.) против Шахматова (Bull. dе l᾽Асаd. dеs Sс. dе St. Pétersbourg, 1911, стр. 810), который считает фин. слово заимств. из праслав. Неудачно произведение из греч. πύργος "башня" (Якобсон, Slav. Word 2, 616) как в фонетическом или в семантическом отношении, так и с точки зрения географии слов. Не имеет ничего общего слово пиро́г с местн. н. Пирогоща, которое происходит от имени собств. Пирогостъ и не может быть сближено с греч. πυργῶτις.